# Question about proof about index and subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group so that $H\lhd G$. There is an element $g \in G$ so that $g$ isn't in $H$ but $g^2$ is in $H$. Show the index is even.

Can't I just say that the cosets of $H$ are $H$ and $Hg$ (because $Hg^2=H$), so that means there are only two cosets, hence the index is even?

Comment: But...your last question (and its answers) together with Lagrange's Theorem should solve this at once!

Comment: This question is without the specific info on order of set and index in my last question.

Comment: so? The given data says $\;2\;$ **must divide** the index ...This is Lagrange!

Comment: See the proof I wrote as a comment to Andreas

Comment: Exactly, @charlie ...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not enough. There could be many more cosets. Consider for instance the [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) $G$, and $H = \{1\}$.

Spoiler

> Show that $g H$ is an element of order $2$ in $G/H$.

Comment: Thanks. So how about this: The order of $Hg$ is some $m \in \mathbb N$ so that $(Hg)^m=H$, or so that $g^m=e \in H$. We know that $g^2 \in H$, so that means 2 divides $m$, and $m$ divides the index (as it is an order of a coset), so that means 2 divides the index -> it's even.

Comment: @charlie, more or less, yes. I would just do it like this: $H g \ne H$, as $g \notin H$, while $(H g)^2 = H g^2 = H$, as $g^2 \in H$, so $H g$ is an element of order $2$ in the group $G/H$, which implies that $2$ divides its order.